# View all validation rules

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-named-ranges, google-sheets-data-validation

I've just created Data Validation for the named range. How can I edit the validation? I tried to click `Data Validation...` on the range, but there is a new validation rule, but not existing for the range (selected ranges are equals). Is there possible to view all validation rules for the sheet?

Comment: Next time, try selecting the whole sheet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not possible, there is no Data validation preview in Google Sheets where you would see the list of all rules you created (like in Conditional formatting, Protected ranges or Named ranges).

Comment: So, there is not way to remove validation rule for named range without removing named range?

Comment: data validation is bound to the cell, not to the named range. named range is just an input. to remove data validation you just need to click on the cell/range you created data validation for and remove it by right-click > data validation > remove

Comment: I checked it one more time. I thought the name range was `X:Y` and I tried to select `X:Y`, but named range was `X:Y-1`. My mistake. Too bad I can't see the whole list of all validation rules. May be later I write add-one for this if it is possible. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you know which cells have validations rules, select that particular cell and go to `data` > `data validation`. It will show the rule, you may edit or delete the same.

[image: Refer image]